# Initialize CCPoint from brace format string

Tags: string, cocos2d-iphone

I've got string like this: {{0,168},{20,20}}, here indicates two points. I want to get them out to initialize my CCPoint. Do you guys know how to convert this?

Answer (score 1):

An easy fix , if you have string in that specific format:

```
    CGRect rect = CGRectFromString(@"{{0,168},{20,20}}");
    CGPoint point1 = CGPointMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y);
    CGPoint point2 = CGPointMake(rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
```

If you have more and you want to get them use this:

```
NSString *string = @"{{0,168},{20,20},{20,20},{20,20},{20,20}}";
NSRange range;
range.length = string.length - 1;
range.location = 1;
//because you have commas everywhere you need to change it to a different separator
NSString *modString = [[string substringWithRange:range] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"},{" withString:@"}#{"];

NSArray *pointList = [modString componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];

for (NSString *str in pointList)
{
    CGPoint point = CGPointFromString(str);
    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGPoint(point));
}
```

Comment: How about more than two sets {{0,168},{20,20}, {20,25}, {30,35}} ? Use string split method?